# Powershell Move-Item Rename If File Exists

Tags: powershell, rename, move

I have a powershell script that takes all of the files in one directory, renames the first one and moves it, and then goes to the next file. Sometimes there will be multiple files that get renamed to the same name (because of the system that it's going to, not ideal and will have to change) and was overwriting files that shouldn't have been getting overwritten with -force. I need all of the files to move but also have unique names so we have them available in the destination location. Is there an easy way to have it automatically rename so it would look like:

123.txt
123(1).txt
123(2).txt

or

123.txt
123_1.txt
123_2.txt

Comment: I have little idea about `powershell` (the name is a joke in itself...), but doesn't it offer some function creating file names being guaranteed to be unique like other environments?

Comment: I found some documentation but didn't see anything about unique names, just that it can force move and overwrite the file that already exists or it throws an error and skips the move, leaving the old file and the new file in their respective directories.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do that. Give this a try:

```
$src = "d:\temp"
$dest = "d:\temp1"
$num=1

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Filter *.txt -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

    $nextName = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.name

    while(Test-Path -Path $nextName)
    {
       $nextName = Join-Path $dest ($_.BaseName + "_$num" + $_.Extension)    
       $num+=1   
    }

    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $nextName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Fixed solution basing on previous answer (variable $num moved into for each loop):

$src = "d:\temp"
$dest = "d:\temp1"

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Filter *.txt -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $num=1
    $nextName = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.name

    while(Test-Path -Path $nextName)
    {
       $nextName = Join-Path $dest ($_.BaseName + "_$num" + $_.Extension)    
       $num+=1   
    }

    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $nextName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm way late to the party here but... I kinda liked the responses just didn't like the lack of it being in a function so... I modified it for re-usability.

I added the Name field because I'm using this as part of another process where I am using a regex substring process to take a file name which contains `<owner>-<date_string>-<hash>.<extension>` and moving them into a `<file_path>/<owner>/<date_string>.<extension>` format.

```
function Move-Item-AutoRename {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [String]$Source,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$Destination,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$Name
    )
    PROCESS {
        $count = 1
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$nextName = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $Name

        while (Test-Path -Path $nextName) {
            $nextName = Join-Path -Path $Destination ($Name.Split(".")[0] + "_$($count)" + $nextName.Extension)
            $count += 1
        }

        Move-Item -Path $Source -Destination $nextName
    }
}
```

Since I am sure others may be interested in the other part of this solution I will include it just for sharing sake.

```
function Import-UnsortedFiles {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [String]$Source,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$Destination
    )
    PROCESS {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Include *.xml, *.json | ForEach-Object {
            $results = $_.Name | Select-String -Pattern '^(.*)-([0-9]*_[0-9]*)-.*(\..*)$'
            [System.IO.FileInfo] $dest = (Join-Path -Path $Target -ChildPath "$($results.Matches.Groups[1])/$($results.Matches.Groups[2])$($results.Matches.Groups[3])");
        
            $test = (Test-Path -Path $dest.Directory.FullName -PathType Container)
            if ($test -eq $false) {
                New-Item -Path $dest.Directory.FullName -ItemType Directory;
            }
        
            Move-Item-AutoRename -Source $_.FullName -Destination $dest.Directory.FullName -Name $dest.Name
        }
    }
}
```

Call this by invoking `Import-UnsortedFiles -Source $Source -Destination $Target`